# creating a module in prestashop: error 'class Module cannot be found'

Tags: php, prestashop

i have a presta module in php4. It works by connecting to the database of a prestashop and prints out xml. Whiles trying to upload to their apps store, they asked i make it php5 and follow certain proceedures.

- In a nutshell, its just a full structural code with 1 method that gets connection to a prestashop database and prints out xml.

So the problem is how to get it to conform to the php5 standard required by prestashop. When i tried, i get this error. "class Module cannot be found"

```
<?php
include('config/settings.inc.php');
$con = mysql_connect(_DB_SERVER_, _DB_USER_, _DB_PASSWD_);
mysql_select_db(_DB_NAME_);
$str = '_DB_PREFIX_';
$str1 = constant($str);
$sql = 'SELECT '.
$str1.'product_lang.name,'.
$str1.'product.id_product as id,'.
$str1.'product.quantity,'.
$str1.'product.price,'.
$str1.'product.weight,'.
$str1.'product_lang.description,'.
$str1.'product_lang.link_rewrite as url,'.
$str1.'category_lang.name as category,'.
$str1.'manufacturer.name as manufacturer,'.
$str1.'image.id_image '.

'FROM '.
$str1.'product_lang '.
'INNER JOIN ' .$str1.'product '.
'ON ('.$str1.'product_lang.id_product = '.$str1.'product.id_product) '.
'INNER JOIN ' .$str1.'image '.
'ON ('.$str1.'image.id_product = '.$str1.'product.id_product) '.
'INNER JOIN ' .$str1.'manufacturer '.
'ON ('.$str1.'manufacturer.id_manufacturer = '.$str1.'product.id_manufacturer) '.
'INNER JOIN ' .$str1.'category_lang '.
'ON ('.$str1.'category_lang.id_category = '.$str1.'product.id_category_default) '.
//'WHERE '.$str1.'product_lang.id_lang = 1 AND '.$str1.'category_lang.id_lang = 1';
    'WHERE '.$str1.'product_lang.id_lang = 1';
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

     header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
     $output = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <products>';
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):
     //echo "<br><br><b>text:</b>".$text = addslashes($text);
     $text = str_replace(chr(145), "\'", $text);
 $output .= '
<product>
    <id>'. $row['id'].'</id>
    <name><![CDATA['.$name.']]></name>
    <description><![CDATA['.$text.']]></description>
            <image><![CDATA['. 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].__PS_BASE_URI__.'img/p/'.$row['id'].'-'.$row['id_image'].'.jpg' .']]></image>
        <quantity><![CDATA['. $row['quantity'] .']]></quantity> 
        <price><![CDATA['. $row['price'] .']]></price>
        <weight>'. $row['weight'] .'</weight>
    <category><![CDATA['.$category.']]></category>
    <manufacturer><![CDATA['. $manufacturer.']]></manufacturer>
            <url><![CDATA['.'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/product.php?id_product='.$row['id'].']]></url>

     </product>';
 endwhile;

 print $output .= '
 </products>';
```

This is the proceedure of coding i need to follow from prestashop

```
<?php
       //Your class must have the same name than this file.

      class module_name extends Module
       {
      public function __construct()
       {

    //Name of your module. It must have the same name than the class
    $this->name = 'module_name';

    //You must choose an existing tab amongst the ones that are available
    $this->tab = 'You choose';

    //The version of your module. Do not forget to increment the version for each modification
    $this->version = '1.0';

    //The constructor must be called after the name has been set, but before you try to use any functions like $this->l()
    parent::__construct();

    //Name displayed in the module list
    $this->displayName = $this->l('Display Name on Back Office');

    //Short description displayed in the module list
    $this->description = $this->l('Description On Back Office');    
}

//You must implement the following methods if your module need to create a table, add configuration variables, or hook itself somewhere.
//-------------------------------
public function install()
{
    return parent::install();
}

public function uninstall()
{
    return parent::install();
}
//-------------------------------

//Display Configuration page of your module.
public function getContent()
{
    return 'Hello World!';
}

   }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a series of articles on writing modules for prestashop some time ago that you may find helpful: [Writing your own Prestashop Module Part 1](http://www.ecartservice.net/17072009/writing-your-own-prestashop-module-part-1/)

These describe the basic architecture and how modules are typically implemented.

I get the feeling though that you wish this script to be standalone rather than the xml generated from within the Backoffice admin screens? If that is the case then this wouldn't be classed as a "Module" by the Prestashop definition, and that would be the reason it has been rejected.

Regardless of whether you're writing a stand-alone script or a module, you also need to use the various Prestashop API calls to retrieve the product information rather than merely executing sql on the raw database tables. The reason for this is that the raw sql will not take into account factors such as language, tax or currency conversion.

An example of how to fetch all the products and print the details about them from within a Prestashop module would be:

```
global $cookie;

$products = Product::getProducts($cookie->id_lang, 0, NULL,'id_product', 'ASC');
foreach ($products AS product) {
  echo 'title: '. $product['name'];
  echo 'weight: '. $product['weight'];
  // .. etc. 
}
```

All the best with your Prestashop programming!

Comment: I'd be happy to look at it and assist, just drop me a message and we can sort something out if you're still working on this.

Comment: ok. posted it on your wall http://www.ecartservice.net/free-prestashop-modules/prestashop-google-product-search/comment-page-1/#comment-14877

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is your code to stand alone. To do this, you need to initialize prestashop yourself. This is likely the most reliable way to do this.

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    require_once '../../config/config.inc.php';
    require_once '../../init.php';
}
```

This will allow you to use the `module` class, as well as anything else from the prestashop framework you need to use.